# Symfony2: Make constraints depend on each other

Tags: php, validation, constraints, symfony

I have the following constraints defined in my Symfony2 entity:

```
* @Assert\NotBlank()
* @Assert\Type(type="numeric")
* @Assert\Min(limit=1)
```

I would like the min validation only to be performed when the value actually passes the numeric validation. Because otherwise I run into a error.

Is there any way to make constraints dependend on each other?

Thx! Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think right now your best option is using a [custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) that does exactly what you want, or a callback assertion as Koc pointed out.

It's strange that you'd get an error though, if the value is not numeric, then it shouldn't even call the Min validator. If you get an exception out of this configuration, you should report it as a bug imo.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [there isn't](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1151) normal sollution from box yet. Maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/980472) helps.